# Selenium screenshot parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, screenshot

Here is my selemium test:

```
    [Test]
    public void RunStepsTest()
    {
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver())
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
            ExecuteStep(driver, "start");
            ExecuteStep(driver, "step1");
            ExecuteStep(driver, "step2");
            ExecuteStep(driver, "finish");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteStep(InternetExplorerDriver driver, string stepName)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(x => ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(stepName)));

        var scrrenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
        scrrenshot.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(ScreenshotDirectory, stepName + ".jpg"), ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);

        var link = driver.FindElement(By.Id(stepName));
        link.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
```

Most of time this test fails on line

```
        scrrenshot.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(ScreenshotDirectory, stepName + ".jpg"), ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

with message "Paramter is not valid". What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you had a look at this thread? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Not exactly sure if it'll work but you could try like it says in the thread I linked:

`File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));`

(sorry, code formatting is so bad in comments)

Comment: @Dillanm I havent found TakesScreenshot type in WebDriver or WebDriver.Support dlls.

Comment: Sorry, in .NET it's `ITakesScreenshot` and it's part of the base `WebDriver.dll` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Internet Explorer driver, it's intended to throw this error .

From [Github bug tracking](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7256) :

> Because of the limitations of how the IE driver is forced to work in
>   order to take full-DOM screenshots, screenshots are only supported for
>   browser windows viewing HTML documents. This is entirely as intended
>   by the driver (regardless of the behavior of Chrome or Firefox). The
>   driver is forced by the constraints of the IE browser itself.
>   Accordingly, I'm closing this as "working as intended".

If you are allowed to use other driver, you can try Firefox or Chrome Driver to have screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I read this. But in my case this is just a simple html document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code like this:

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile("e:\\pande", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: this doesnt help